# hdwallet provider create wallet for user

Tags: javascript, html, ethereum, solidity, truffle

I have created a smart contract that facilitates a token sale. I want a user to be able to press a button that automatically generates an ERC20 wallet that tokens can be sent to.

I am using the truffle HDWallet Provider and Infura. I don't want the user to have to use MetaMask or anything else. I will sign the transactions on the backend using the private key of the user's generated wallet.

How would I go about implementing this so a new wallet is created for every new user that wants to perform a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that allowed me to create a wallet on a button press. I now need to find a way to store the credentials of these wallets so I can sign transactions and transfer tokens to them.

```
  var bip39 = require('bip39');
  const EthereumUtil = require('ethereumjs-util');
  const hdkey = require('hdkey');

  const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic(); //generates string
  const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic); //creates seed buffer

  const root = hdkey.fromMasterSeed(seed);
  const masterPrivateKey = root.privateKey.toString('hex');

  const addrNode = root.derive("m/44'/60'/0'/0/0");
  const pubKey = EthereumUtil.privateToPublic(addrNode._privateKey);
  const addr = EthereumUtil.publicToAddress(pubKey).toString('hex');
  const address = EthereumUtil.toChecksumAddress(addr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple, just create a HDWalletProvider and the `provider.addresses` has all the accounts you can use:

Here is the code:

```
const createWallet =  function(_providerUrl) {
    const mnemonicPhrase = bip39.generateMnemonic()
    let provider = new HDWalletProvider({
        mnemonic: {
            phrase: mnemonicPhrase
        },
        providerOrUrl: "http://localhost:8545"
    });
    return provider.addresses
}
```

Addresses has the accounts

Answer (score 0):

The solution has already been commented above, but I have a better suggestion for you. I think it's better to generate only one mnemonic in your backend and you create infinite accounts from that mnemonic. From each account you extract the private key and store it, store the address of the account and the index of the account.

Management code:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const mnemonicPhrase = "mnemonicPhrase here"; 
const urlRPC = "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org"; 

//Creating another instance to query balances
const Web3Instance = require('web3');
const web3instance = new Web3Instance(new Web3Instance.providers.HttpProvider(urlRPC));

//HD Wallet Provider loads by default only 10 accounts
//We change the limit to as many accounts as we want
//You cannot run the loop below for i greater than 10, because for
const limit = 50;

async function getAccount() {

  provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: mnemonicPhrase,
    numberOfAddresses: limit,
    providerOrUrl: urlRPC,
    addressIndex: 0,

    });

  //HDWalletProvider is compatible with Web3
  //Use it at Web3 constructor, just like any other Web3 Provider
  const web3 = new Web3(provider);

  //I realized that iterating a loop to limit always gives an error when it reaches limit
  //This happens in this HD Wallet Provider package
  //limit - 1 seems to work best
  for (let i = 0; i < limit - 1; i ++) {

    var get = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    var address = get[i];
    var balanceETH = await web3instance.eth.getBalance(address)

    //Checking the adress
    console.log(address);
    console.log(balanceETH);

  }

}

getAccount();
```

Here is more information:
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52370/web3-create-account-from-mnemonic-passphrase/144340#144340